# Apps Script & Analytics: When I retrive the avgTimeOnSite value from the API I get a wrong format number

Tags: google-apps-script, number-formatting

I´m using the "Magic" code from Apps Script to get data from the Analytics API and get it into Spreadsheet.

One of the values I need is the avgTimeOnSite. It is supposed to return the time in seconds. My problem is how to translate the number to a usefull HH.MM.SS format.

Sometimes I get these numbers:

584.123076923077
In the first case I get a logical number (584/60 seconds = 9,73 minutes). But when I try to get an integer from that number =INT(584.123076923077) I get 584.123.076.923.077,00. Obviously I´m having a format problem and the systems is messing the amercican format (integer.decimal) with the latin system (integer,decimal).

581095
In the second case I get a huge integer number. I think must be related to the same problem.

Any clue on how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the post answer your question? If so please use the "tick" option to mark that response as the answer. If not, you should edit your question and clarify it so people have an opportunity to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet hosting your "Google Analytics Report Automation (magic)" code, go into File > Spreadsheet settings and check the "Locale".

Make sure it is in a locale that supports the dot as the decimal point rather than the comma.

If that fixes your problem then you'll need to keep the setting like this or patch the "magic" code (shouldn't be too difficult).